# C++ enum flag usage

Tags: c++, enums

I've googled around but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer immediately available. I'm trying to figure out the proper usage of enum flags in C++. I'm working on a 2D tile based platformer engine and I want to give each tile flags that determine which edges can be collided with.

In one file I have:

```
enum CollidableEdges
{
    TopEdge = 1,
    RightEdge = 2,
    BottomEdge = 4,
    LeftEdge = 8
};
```

How do I actually call these flags in an object and use them in logic later on? In the examples I've looked at online it doesn't seem to declare an enum anywhere besides the initial list when manipulating flags. Can someone clarify what exactly is happening and how to use it? For example, when creating a new Tile object with a definition something like this:

```
class Tile: public Entity
{
    public:
        Tile(std::string obstacleTexture, int, int);
}
```

I'm a fairly new programmer, so I'm sure I'm using bad practices or am missing something obvious. Don't be shy in telling me.

Comment: You use a type of CollidableEdges and assign it a value from your enum .

Comment: Do you intend to combine the enums? Like `CollidableEdges::TopEdge|CollidableEdges::RightEdge`

Comment: As in having multiple edges flagged? Yes. Unless you mean something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone clarify what exactly is happening and how to use it?

To initialize particular bits

```
uint8_t flags = uint8_t(TopEdge) | uint8_t(LeftEdge);
```

To set particular bits

```
flags |= uint8_t(BottomEdge);
```

To clear particular bits

```
flags &= ~(uint8_t(TopEdge) | uint8_t(LeftEdge));
```

To test for particular bits

```
if(flags & uint8_t(BottomEdge) > 0) { // Flag is set (BottomEdge)
}
```

The reason you need to cast it, is because if you have an expression like `TopEdge | LeftEdge` the compiler won't accept the original `enum`type as result.

To get rid of the casts, you can also define an overloaded `operator|()`,`operator&()`,etc.:

```
CollidableEdges operator|(CollidableEdges  left, CollidableEdges right) {
    return static_cast<CollidableEdges>(static_cast<unsigned>(left) | 
                                        static_cast<unsigned>(right));
}
// etc.
```

which allows to write simply

```
CollidableEdges edges = TopEdge | LeftEdge;
```

**NOTE:**
Though the above statements will work fine, IMHO they give bad readability for the intended semantics. I personally prefer the following solution:

```
 enum class CollidableEdgeBitPos : size_t {
    TopEdge ,
    RightEdge ,
    BottomEdge ,
    LeftEdge 
 };

 typedef std::bitset<4> CollidableEdges;

 CollidableEdges edges;

 edges[CollidableEdgeBitPos::RightEdge] = true;
 edges[CollidableEdgeBitPos::BottomEdge] = false;
```

Comment: For your unset particular bits example, your parens don't match, and it should be `&=` rather than `|=` (right now you're **setting** all bits except `TopEdge` and `LeftEdge`).

Comment: It's usual to define overloaded operators for such enums, so that `TopEdge | LeftEdge` would have type `CollidableEdges`.

Comment: @JamesKanze But wouldn't that lead to a kind of _invalid cast_ (I don't mean the actual compiler error) to `CollidableEdges` where the combination of the values wasn't ever defined?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No.  In fact, it's guaranteed that the results will work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you two are talking about but a little bit of tweaking and the flags are now properly setting. Thank you!

Comment: @user3507582 THX for accepting. _'but a little bit of tweaking ...'_ Sorry, all of the samples I gave were just _free air coded_ (I didn't compile to test them). Please let me now what's left to tweak, such I can fix my answer.

Comment: Your code was fine. I meant tweaking in the context of my project.

Comment: this is great and solves the problem. now I applied it to a similar flags enum, where I have `AllEdges = LeftEdge | TopEdge | RightEdge | BottomEdge` in the declaration of the enum, resulting in an "expression must have a constant value" compile-time error, which goes away if I remove the | operator's definition.

Answer (score 0):

`CollidableEdges` is a type you can use it anywhere you can use a type (e.g. it could be the type of one of the parameters in your method.

The labels of the enum are identifiers valid in the containing scope of the enum. For example, if you define the enum within a `class XX`, the labels can be reached using `XX::TopEdge`

You can cast to/from int, but it is best to check (e.g. switch/case) instead of blind cast from int.

Casting to int results in the value associated to the label. This is an alternative to static const integer constants. So for example, in your example where each label is associated a bit-wise disjoint value, you can combine the labels using the bitwise or (e.g TopEdge|LefEdge) [but only because they are disjoint integer values).

Comment: I have the enum declared in a global file. If I put a CollidableEdges enum into the class in the header file, will that suffice? I'm just confused as to how this will all tie in together.

Comment: @user3507582 You can have it global, I was only underlying the scope rules for the labels. If you have the enum defined at the global scope, the identifier would be at the global scope.

Comment: Will they be combined within the scope of my tile object if I set the flags at different times? For example if I set TopEdge within one if statement, and then RightEdge within another if statement, will they both be flagged as valid?

Comment: @user3507582 _'will they both be flagged as valid?'_ No, see my answer how to manipulate the single bits (flags).

Answer (score 0):

Given the numerical values, it looks like your enum is being
used to define bit masks.  In such cases, the usual procedure
would be to overload the relevant operators for them, so that
you can use them appropriately:

```
inline CollidableEdges
operator|( CollidableEdges lhs, CollidableEdges rhs )
{
    return static_cast<CollidableEdges>(
        static_cast<unsigned>( lhs) | static_cast<unsigned>( rhs ) );
}
```

etc.  (You'll want `|`, `|=`, `&`, `&=` and `~`.)  These
operators should generally go in the same header as the enum
definition.  Objects which use them would then also take
a `CollidableEdge` as an argument:

```
Tile::Tile( std::string const& texture, CollidableEdge edges )...
```

etc.

Traditionally, the names of the enumeration constants are
defined in the same scope as the enum itself; in C++11, you also
have the possibility of restricting them to the enum, by
declaring `enum class CollidableEdge`, rather than
`enum CollidableEdge`; in that case, you would have to specify
`CollidableEdge::TopEdge | CollidableEdge::LeftEdge`, rather
than just `TopEdge | LeftEdge`.  (On the other hand, it means
that they won't collide with any other symbols you might want to
define.)

Finally, given the "wrong" precedance of `|` and `&`, I've often
found it convenient to define the operators `+`, `-` and `*` as
well, with `a + b` the equivalent of `a | b` (you're adding values to
the set), `a - b` the equivalent of `a & ~ b` (you're subtracting
values from the set) and `a * b` the same as `a & b`.